# Correction for Satellite Images

Tags: raster, landsat-8

I have found that some Landsat images undergo image corrections like: TOA Radiance, Satellite Brightness Temperature and other corrections. What are some of the image corrections required mandatory to work before working on these images or are they free from error these days?

Comment: This sort of opinion based questions are discouraged in GIS SE. You can discuss it in [gis chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=gis.stackexchange.com) or other discussion forums,

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with them. You could improve your question by narrowing it down to a very specific single topic. [This](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange) is also useful.